# Powercfg Help scrolls too fast to read

Tags: windows-7

When I execute Powercfg Help from within the Start message box, Powercfg scrolls by too fast to read.
How can I slow or stop 'Help' to allow line by line readability?

Answer (score 4):

You need to pipe it through `more`. Try `powercfg -help | more`.

Answer (score 3):

You could redirect it into a text file - `powercfg -h > foo.txt` then open foo.txt in your default text editor. Unlike using more, or increasing the size of your cmd window, this gives you a searchable, scrollable, easily copyable copy of the help instructions in the text editor of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

Use the CMDprompt instead cmd.exe and , Adjust the screen buffer
[image]

The Height there of the "screen buffer" seems to change the ammount of scrollable history of what happens in the CMD window. By adjusting this to a larger ammount, you could scoll back through even larger ammounts of information.

I do not know if it helps to know this, or even if I say it correctly.
The CMD prompt has a lot of obscure settings that somehow were supposed to understand.  I never did understand them :-)  I have just changed and messed with a lot of stuff, trying to get desired results.

This does not apply to "run" or other methods. I have always made a Shortcut for the CMDprompt, then adjusted the "properties" for that shortcut item, to have a more usable CMD prompt. Then I always run the CMDprompt from that shortcut item.   There is a "Command History" "Buffer Size" in the Options too, I assume for flipping back through previosly entered commands.